# Python suds parsing response

Tags: python, suds

I am using python 3.4 with suds i have the following code.

```
client = Client(url, faults=False)
result = client.service.SubmitTimes(apikey=apiKey, times=data)
print ("result",result)
```

That result =

```
result (200, (SqlInsertBase){
SqlInsertOk = True
})
```

I am trying to get what the value of SqlInsertOk equals.

i tried doing result.SqlInsertOk but that errors. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I remove Faults=false then it works.